# Eloquent Relationship Table Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

so I want to connect two data from the sales table and sales_item table, what I want to call is sales_date. So sales_date is in the sales table and I want to display it in the controller without in view. And I have a foreign key called sales_id and I want to display a chart for this task

so i try called with function in my model Sales.php

```
public function callSalesItem()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(SalesItem::class, 'sales_id');
    }
```

and this function in model SalesItem.php

```
public function callSales()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Sales::class,'sales_id');
    }
```

and this is my controller

```
 public function grafik()
    {
         $sales_item_total_price = SalesItem::with(DB::raw("CAST(SUM(sales_item_total_price) as int)as sales_item_total_price"))
        ->GroupBy(DB::raw("Year(sales_date)"))
        ->pluck('sales_item_total_price');


        $tahun = Sales::select(DB::raw("YEAR(sales_date) as tahun"))
        ->GroupBy(DB::raw("YEAR(sales_date)"))
        ->pluck('tahun');
        

        return view('content/Penjualan/GrafikPenjualan',compact('sales_item_total_price','tahun')); 
    }
```

and this is my view to make a chart

```
@extends('adminlte::page')

@section('title', 'Tanggapan')

@section('content_header')
    
<nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
    <ol class="breadcrumb">
        <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="{{ url('home') }}">Beranda</a></li>
        <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Daftar Produk Kategori</li>
    </ol>
</nav>

@stop

@section('content')

<h3 class="page-title">
    <b>Grafik Penjualan </b> <small>Mengelola Grafik Penjualan </small>
</h3>
<br/>
@if(session('msg'))
<div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
    {{session('msg')}}
</div>
@endif 
<div class="card border border-dark">
    <div class="card-header bg-dark clearfix">
        <h5 class="mb-0 float-left">
            Daftar
        </h5>
        <div class="form-actions float-right">
            <button onclick="location.href='{{ url('productcategory/tambah') }}'" name="Find" class="btn btn-sm btn-info" title="Add Data"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Tambah Produk Baru</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <div id="grafik"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript">    
        var pendapatan = <?php echo json_encode($sales_item_total_price) ?>;  
        var tahun = <?php echo json_encode($tahun) ?>;
        Highcharts.chart('grafik', {
            title : {
                text : 'Grafik Penjualan Tahunan'
            },
            xAxis : {
                categories : tahun
            },
            yAxis : {
                title: {
                    text : 'Nominal Pendapatan Tahunan'
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    allowPointSelect: true
                }
            },
            series: [
                {
                    name: 'Nominal Pendapatan',
                    data: pendapatan
                }
            ]
        });
        
        </script>
    
    @stop
    
    @section('footer')
    
    @stop
    
@section('css')
    
@stop

@section('js')
    
@stop
```

so the error because of model SalesItem.php dont have column sales_date and i want to call sales_date from model Sales.php

can anyone help this?

Comment: A sale has many saleItems right?

Comment: is the function reversed?@KhangTran

Comment: I think so. Can you show the migration?

Comment: i dont use migration because i got the database from my school

Comment: So can you show the structure of your tables?

Comment: bruh nevermind my teacher told me to use created_at im so sorry

Comment: he said to just make it simple, im really angry with my teacher right now